# java stuck in loop when printing characters

Tags: java

I have a IBM Notes Java agent.
In this agent I post data to a PHP file.
This PHP eventually does an echo like : "Records updated successfully"

Now in my java agent at the end of my post I have this:

```
for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;){
                System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

But in my logfile per post i see now this

```
24-01-2017 13:57:45   AMgr: Agent  printing: R
24-01-2017 13:57:45   AMgr: Agent  printing: e
24-01-2017 13:57:45   AMgr: Agent  printing: c
```

so it prints every character individually why is that??

Comment: what are you expecting from a method like `public int read()` ? It simply return the character and you print it directly in your out Stream. What is the problem ?

Comment: Where does in come from?

Comment: @axelh but there shouldn't be a new line after each print with all the overhead.

Comment: Have you replaced your system.out with something else for logging purposes?

Comment: No but system.out prints out as system.out.println thats just weird

Comment: @Cruncher From the looks of it whatever logger system bboni is using will convert each System.out.print into an own line ( And also adding timestamp stuff in front of it).

Comment: @Cruncher My bad, I have edited the question (format) because I didn't notice the problem. I thouth this was the line to print. This is the logging system used that change the format.

Comment: @bboni I'm sure it is. Anyway, the solution is easy. Build your result into a string, and only print once. Clearly your logger doesn't care about print vs. println

Comment: what is stuck in loop? you command `print(c)`, the logging correctly states "printing: `c`" meaning something like "the method 'print' was called with argument `c`". print is called individually so logging is also done individually.

Comment: Could you please post this as an anwser @Cruncher and Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Take the echo data as an `InputStream` with a `java.util.Scanner` and then do a `System.out.println()` with only that String value. You don't need to cycle through each character individually.

Alternatively, you could just make a new string and do a `string += character;` during every recursion.

```
String output = "";
for(int c = 0; (c = n.read()) >= 0;){
        output += (char)c;
}
System.out.print(output);
```